# is it easy to write own drivers?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose i have here a new Bluetooth PS joystick. Would it be easy to write a driver for it to work with ros? would it be a lot harder than writing a sensor for Ubuntu Linux?

Thanks in advance, i'm very novice in this matters.

greetings ros community

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52255/is-it-easy-to-write-own-drivers?/) by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS already has PS3 joystick drivers, see:

> http://www.ros.org/wiki/ps3joy

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-01-14**:
And probably several packages converting buttons into robot commands you could use as a template. Like [my teleop_ps3 package](https://github.com/felix-kolbe/uashh-rvl-ros-pkg/tree/master/teleop_ps3).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't say that it is always easy, but IMO it certainly is no harder than writing a sensor driver for Ubuntu Linux.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One more general hint: If your new device has no ROS support yet, but already a linux driver, it would suffice to write a ROS wrapper for that driver.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-15**:
And, don't forget to ask the ROS community. Often, someone else is already working on it.